# clickable link in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

This code works correctly and creates the clickable URL. But I will like to make the "**name**" column clickable and hide url. Is it possible?

```
data = [dict(name='Google', url='http://www.google.com'),
        dict(name='Stackoverflow', url='http://stackoverflow.com')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val, val)

df.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df['nameurl'] = df['name'] + '#' + df['url']

def make_clickable_both(val): 
    name, url = val.split('#')
    return f'<a href="{url}">{name}</a>'

df.reset_index().style.format({'nameurl': make_clickable_both})
```

Comment: Good one. We could also use a lambda function instead of having make_clickable as a separate function

Comment: Stuck on this. 
How do i apply that Style Format to tha dataframe Permanetly?
I would really like to have a column that reads as a string of link,link,link,link with different websites that are actually linked depending on the row

Answer (score 1):

The end destination of your data frame was left unstated however if your plan to output to html, the following should work best.

```
 df['Url'] = '<a href=' + df['Url'] + '><div>' + df['Name'] + '</div></a>'
 df = df.to_html(escape=False)
```