# Clickable hyperlink on Pandas Dataframe and pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, hyperlink

I have a code that opens a csv file that has playlist and url links to music. When the frame opens on a tkinter window while using pandas dataframe the url hyperlinks are not clickable.. I have tried doing the following from this [clickable link in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209206/clickable-link-in-pandas-dataframe)

The code i have is the following:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Title', 'Link'])

    cols = list(df.columns)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(my_w)
    tree.pack()
    tree["columns"] = cols
    for i in cols:
        tree.column(i, anchor="w")
        tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
       tree.insert("", 0, text=index, values=list(row))
```

but the Link column is not clickable

[image: Hyperlink not clickable]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Tkinter** to create a desktop app, you'll need a way to send a hyperlink to your web browser.  Have you tried this example that uses the web browser package?

[Hyperlink in **Tkinter**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-with-a-label-in-tkinter#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20add%20a,browser%20to%20follow%20the%20link.)

I would suggest getting a single clickable hyperlink to work outside of the pandas data frame first.  Once that's functioning properly, insert the working concept in your iterrows loop.

Comment: I have tried that too but I get an error that I can't add button to index iteration or I am not doing that correctly. And not sure how to add the button next to url maybe to a new column?